# Jsoup not able to read a tag well when there is a sibling

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I meet a problem when I try to use Jsoup to find all

tag. For the following HTML.

```html
<p> xxx <a href="URL"> yyy </a> zzz <!--</p-->
```

and I want to separately print xxx, yyy, and zzz.

My original code is

```html
Document doc;
            doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
        Elements elements = doc.body().select("*");

        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element.ownText());
        }
```

which will givve me output

> xxxzzz
>
> yyy

my preferred output will be

> xxx
>
> yyy
>
> zzz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSoup - How to parse nested texts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262411/jsoup-how-to-parse-nested-texts)

Comment: @PythonLearner not really but I get my own solution already, thanks